# Overwrite colorbar labels Bokeh

Tags: gis, bokeh, overwrite, colorbar

I tried to overwrite the colorbar labels, though I can not get it done, if someone could find out what is wrong in the code and let me know, it would be very appreciate. I can share the data if necessary. I also would like to know if it is possible to use widgets SELECT to select which county and hide the others, as callback.

Regards

```
palleteG = ['#39FF14', '#4CBB17', '#50C878', '#00A572','#2E8B57', '#0b6623'] #'#98FB98','#ffffff','#D0F0C0'
#color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palleteG, low = 25000, high = 450000)
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palleteG, low = irl['2016'].min()*1.01, high = irl['2016'].max()*1.01)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=6,
                    width=500, height=20, border_line_color=None,
                    location='center', orientation='horizontal', 
                    major_label_overrides=tick_labels,
                    bar_line_color='#50C878',
                    bar_line_alpha=0.7)
ps = figure(title = 'Irish Housing Stock 2016', tools = 'pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset, hover, save',
            tooltips = [('County', '@COUNTY'),('Housing Stock','@2016'), ('Population','@Population'),
                       ('Number of Social Housing necessary','@Solution')], #,], 
            x_axis_location = None, y_axis_location = None, plot_width=600, plot_height=800)

ps.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha = 0.7, fill_color = {'field':'2016', 'transform':color_mapper}, line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.5,
           source = geo_source) # fill_color = 'green' 
ps.grid.grid_line_color=None
ps.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
show(ps)
output_file('IHS.html', mode='inline')
```

[image]
[image: An updated version]
The challenge now it's find the right tune for the bar.

Comment: My bad.'````tick_labels = {'25000':'25K','45000':'45K','65000':'65K','85000':'85K','150000':'150K','450000':'450K'}````

Comment: I beg to differ man.